# Create editable set of model objects in django admin

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create editable set of objects.
I have Visitor model, which can contain set of models Sibling. But the set may be blank. This set should be editable in Django admin, and, I would like it will be generated by built-in tools.

Here is my approach to do this:

```
class Sibling(models.Model):
    VisitorID = models.ForeignKey('Visitor')
    # ... some fields

class Visitor(models.Model):
    # ... some fields

    Siblings = models.ManyToManyField(Sibling, blank=True)
```

It is bad way because there are all Siblings from all Visitors in the auto-generated form in django admin, but I want only those which are related to specific Visitor.

Could anyone help me or give advice?

Comment: You have both a foreign key from Siblings, and a many to many key in Visitor.  I don't think you need the latter

Comment: @joelgoldstick If I remove the many to many relation then I won't have Siblings edit form on generated page for Visitor. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way achieve this with a Serializer class

```
class Sibling(models.Model):
    VisitorID = models.ForeignKey('Visitor')
    # ... some fields


class Visitor(models.Model):
    # ... some fields


class VisitorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    sibling = serializers.RelatedField(source='sibling')

    class Meta:
        model = Visitor
        # List all fields in Visitor plus sibling
        fields = ('id', 'somefieldinvisitormodel', 'sibling')
```

The serializer class allows you to override what's being displayed in admin without having to mess with your models. This also allows you to remove the extra relationship you added within visitor.

This isn't an entirely automated solution, but it's close.